# Trying to follow declarative package management fails

Tags: nixos

I am trying to achieve a simple declarative package management solution.

I have a clean nixos installation on virtualbox (thanks to [this vagrant solution](https://app.vagrantup.com/nixos/boxes/nixos-16.09-x86_64) )

I am following [the following subsection in the nixos manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-declarative-package-management)

I do

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/nixpkgs/
vi ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix
```

such that `cat ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix` would now give:

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: with pkgs; {
    myPackages = pkgs.buildEnv {
      name = "my-packages";
      paths = [ aspell bc coreutils gdb ffmpeg nixUnstable emscripten jq nox silver-searcher ];
    };
  };
}
```

And now,

`nix-env -iA nixpkgs.myPackages` outputs:

```
error: attribute ‘nixpkgs’ in selection path ‘nixpkgs.myPackages’ not found
```

I have also tried

```
nix-env -f. -iA nixpkgs.myPackages
nix-env -iA nixos.myPackages
nix-env -f. -iA nixos.myPackages
```

And all fail similarly.

What is a simple example of a package declaration in nixos? In this case, it seems like it tries to achieve a certain set of packages installed *for a given user* . I would not mind a declaration that applies to all users, but would prefer something for a given user (for future use).

EDIT: Here is the outputs when trying to get nix-info

```
[vagrant@nixbox:~]$ nix-shell -p nix-info --run nix-info
error: undefined variable ‘nix-info’ at (string):1:66
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)

[vagrant@nixbox:~]$ nix-shell -p nix-info --run nix-info --show-trace
error: while evaluating the attribute ‘nativeBuildInputs’ of the derivation ‘shell’ at /nix/store/5cd5ac78p0yy47yi5ml12s690bl5lsh8-nixos-16.09.1389.d7a3160/nixos/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix:10:14:
while evaluating ‘optionals’ at /nix/store/5cd5ac78p0yy47yi5ml12s690bl5lsh8-nixos-16.09.1389.d7a3160/nixos/lib/lists.nix:185:21, called from /nix/store/5cd5ac78p0yy47yi5ml12s690bl5lsh8-nixos-16.09.1389.d7a3160/nixos/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix:204:16:
while evaluating ‘chooseDevOutputs’ at /nix/store/5cd5ac78p0yy47yi5ml12s690bl5lsh8-nixos-16.09.1389.d7a3160/nixos/lib/attrsets.nix:463:22, called from /nix/store/5cd5ac78p0yy47yi5ml12s690bl5lsh8-nixos-16.09.1389.d7a3160/nixos/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix:161:22:
undefined variable ‘nix-info’ at (string):1:66

[vagrant@nixbox:~]$
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have a `<nixpkgs>`, based on your first error message. Could you run `echo $NIX_PATH` and `nix-channel --list`?